# How to create a custom form only for WP User Avatar plugin to update user profile pic from front end

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using WP User Avatar plugin in WordPress theme. I want a option in front end to change the profile picture with this plugin. Can any one help me in this. I don't want theme my login plugin suggestions, I'm already using it. It is calling all the fields. But I want only Profile pic change option.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the code you are looking for is...

```
  <?php do_action('edit_user_profile',$current_user); ?>
```

It can be customised slightly by editing the function.php file as detailed here - [WP USER AVATAR CUSTOM](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-user-avatar/other_notes/)